# 32bit vs 64bit Operating systems on Virtual Servers/EC2

Tags: linux, operating-system, 64-bit, debian, 32bit-64bit

Is there any reason to choose a 64bit debian over a 32bit debian instance on Amazon EC2?
64bit Apps simply take more memory (which is crucial & has a high premium in VPS & Cloud servers).

Are there any other things that I should consider in making this choice?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

64-bit apps will use the 64-bit instruction set which carries a great deal more optimisations than default x86 packages Which *can* result in better performance as compared to its x86 counterpart.

Comment: Thanks! Are there any benchmark testing on some of the popular software stacks -- JVM, Apache, MySQL etc?

Comment: this will give you a rough idea: http://www.scribd.com/doc/363677/Benchmarks-AMD64-in-32bit-mode-vs-64bit-mode-Ubuntu

Do also note that if you were to custom compile all the packages you wanted with *all* x86 optimisations enabled (such as SSE2/3/4 etcetera) you may be able to achieve comparable performance under x86